# how route works in laravel with parameter

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

Maybe this is a very basic question but,
In laravel if i use this route:

```
Route::get('/{campo}','ItemController@show');
```

and then i try to use this route

```
Route::get('/mondo/','ItemController@mondo');
```

I get simply redirect to a ItemController@show with parameter 'mondo' but I can't reach ItemController@mondo because he take mondo like a parameter. How can I let laravel know when i want he take a variable from url and when i don't?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just have to change the order:

```
Route::get('mondo','ItemController@mondo');

Route::get('{campo}','ItemController@show');
```

Laravel takes what comes first and your `{campo}` route was accepting every word you had in your URL.

Comment: seems like that you are my savior

Answer (score 0):

Just flip your order.

first route to second and second one to first one